# How to do left outer join and count in AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am trying to get count of tenant for the owner,

owner_collection:

```
[ 
{_id: ObjectId("123dddfffaaa7744"), owner_name:"Sam"},
{_id: ObjectId("243dddfffaaa7755"), owner_name:"Ray"}
]
```

tenant_collection:

```
[
{_id: ObjectId("2223dddfffaaa12233"), tenant_name:"tet", owner_id: ObjectId("123dddfffaaa7744")},
{_id: ObjectId("3343dddfffaaa12234"), tenant_name:"sothy", owner_id: ObjectId("123dddfffaaa7744")},
{_id: ObjectId("6583dddfffaaa1876"), tenant_name:"gill", owner_id: ObjectId("243dddfffaaa7755")},
{_id: ObjectId("2223dddfffaaa12233"), tenant_name:"tony", owner_id: ObjectId("123dddfffaaa7744")}
]
```

In mongodb as it is like this,

```
db.getCollection("owner_collection").aggregate([
    {
         $lookup:{from:"tenant_collection",localField:"_id",foreignField:"owner_id", as:"tenantCount"}
    },{
        $addFields:{
                 tenantCount:{$size:"$tenantCount"}
        }
   }
]);
```

but when i am executing this in aws DocumentDB (mongodb compatibile), it throws error

```
invalid $lookup namespace
```

Is there any way to achieve in DocumentDB ?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the collection you are joining from (tenant_collection) doesn't exist, that is the standard error message of DocumentDB for such a case. This is a different behavior than MongoDB, which doesn't complain when joining with non-existing collection and returns the results from the left hand side collection.
To double check on this, just create an empty collection in DocumentDB and run the $lookup again ( *db.createCollection("tenant_collection")* )